# Transforming a square matrix A into B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let's say I have $A= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}$. How do I figure out the elements of $M$ such that $M^{-1} A M = B$?

Note that in my case, $A$ and $B$ commute, and both are already diagonal and hermitian (they are elements of the Cartan subalgebra of SU(3)). Using these property I can't seem to obtain an expression for $M$ in terms of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You need that $A$ and $B$ have same rank.

Comment: the equation $AM=MB$ is a system of $3^2$ linear equations in the $3^2$ unknown entries of $M$ which you can solve using linear algebra.

Comment: Not quite, @yoyo. The equations are not independent, and the zero matrix is always the solution. There can be different non-zero solutions (and I don't just mean $xM$). If $A$ and $B$ have a different Jordan canonical representation, you can't get such an $M$ (for which there is an inverse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that "$A$, $B$ hermitian and diagonal" is not enough for $M$ to exist.

In fact, $M^{-1}AM=B$ implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities. In other words, the diagonal of $B$ should be a permutation of the diagonal of $A$. So you can take $M$ to be the permutation matrix that permutes the diagonal of $A$ into the diagonal of $B$.

For example, if 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ 
B=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix},
$$
you can take 
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Exactly. An even more direct observation is that $\lambda_8$ is invertible, while $\lambda_3$ isn't.